# How can I get four icons on the same line in the table header with bootstrap table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 4 table icons in my table header. First I gonna show you some screenshots:

[image: screen 1]

This is the table header with 4 icons. This is a situation when the users has a big screen.

When I resize the window I get something like this:

[image: resize]

Users who has a small screen it will resize. The problem is that the 3th icon goes to the next line. What I wanna achieve is when the users has a small screen or resize the window I want the icons on the same line.

This is my code for my table:

```
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>
      <i class="icon-move column-drag"></i>Header 1
      <i class="icon-sorting-up table-icon"></i>
      <i class="icon-basket table-icon"></i>
      <i class="icon-filter table-icon"></i>
    </th> 
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>  
      <td>test</td>   
    </tr>   
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is my css class for `table-icon`

```
  .table-icon {
    color: #CFD2DC;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 27px;
    margin-right: -16px;
}
```

I use a own font package from fontello.

When the user resize the window or has a small monitor how can I get the icons still on the same line? I have used `col-xl` but didn't work for me.

Comment: Set a `min-width` on the `th` so that it will never go small enough to cause a line-break

Comment: What do you want expected behavior to be? Should the table have a minimum size? In which case @RoryMcCrossan suggestion would work, or do you want the text to dissapear with an ellips behind the icons? You could also collapse them into a dropdown on smaller screens. Telling us what you want to happen would make it easier to help you

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have use `min-width: 50%` and it get responsive till 1716 X 1198. 

When the screen gets smaller I want the icons still on the same line and not to the next line. @LiefdeWen

Comment: @Fearcoder Then instead use a pixel based min-width. The result will be icons on one line but on smaller screens your table will be more wide than the screen.

Example of pixel based min width: `th { min-width: 150px }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the utility class `.text-nowrap` to the table header:

```
<th class="text-nowrap">
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/text/#text-wrapping-and-overflow

Comment: See here using font awesome icons https://jsfiddle.net/chan_omega/jaLzrhvq/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```html
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1 <span><i class="icon-move column-drag">1</i><i class="icon-sorting-up">2</i><i class="icon-basket">3</i><i class="icon-filter">4</i></span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The icons in your solutions are now in different headers. The icons must be in one header

Comment: Yes something like this: header 1 [icon 1] [icon 2] [icon 3]

Comment: Then in snippet there is same. I cant't get icons so i gave numbers instead of icons. In result it is the same as you wanted. Header 1 [1] [2] [3] [4]. @Fearcoder

Comment: You have the icons now in separates headers instead of next to each other

Answer (score 0):

Use `media-queries` to adjust ui.

smartphones, portrait iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones (Android)

```
@media (min-width:320px)  { 
   font-size: 27px;  //change these
   margin-right: -16px; //change these

}
```

Comment: i am want you to change something like this: font-size: 10%;

Comment: I have changed to percentage but get the same result when I resizing the window

Comment: Okay you have to use media queries. its a css feature to adjust the ui when used on different devices.